# Labels for firebase push notifications

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I try to attach some descriptive labels to firebase push notifications and use the official SDK on the server to send the push notifications and the label.
However in the firebase console reporting page no labels appear for 2 weeks now.

Are labels only meant for data notifications and not for user facing push notifications?

Thats the payload sent to the firebase servers:

```json
{
  "notification" : {
    "title" : "Test",
    "body" : "Test",
    "sound" : "DEFAULT"
  },
  "data" : {
    "no" : "data"
  },
  "priority" : "HIGH",
  "to" : "...nIAUefzlCc",
  "fcm_options" : {
    "analytics_label" : "rating"
  }
}
```

So the `analytics_label` is correctly present. The firebase account is also linked to a google analytics account with shared data as described in the docs.

The app is using the official firebase/google analytics SDKs.